# Is there a vertical highlighting feature in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

In MS Visual Studio, you can hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and make text selections vertically. Is this feature available in NetBeans on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively NetBeans does not support rectangular/vertical selection, but there is a [plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=1174) available that does exactly that. Also - take a look at this [discussion](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13857) in the NetBeans issue tracker.

Comment: Or the square dotted icon with the small arrow located at the document toolbar in Netbeans 8.

Answer (score 42):

This is supported natively in NetBeans as of 7.1 http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13857

Use `Command-Shift-R`

Comment: Not a feature that you need often, but it's invaluable when you do need it!

Comment: This toggles the select mode on/off

Comment: As of 8.2 you apparently can't just make a rectangular selection at once as in any other editor: you need to switch on rectangular mode, make your selection and switch it off again.

Answer (score 18):

In Netbeans 7.2, this feature is available. 
If you are using Windows, you can toggle the rectangular selection by pressing the

```
Ctrl + Shift + R
```

Also there is an icon (dotted rectangle with an arrow pointer) in the **Editor Toolbar**.